# ATA errors on laptop

Tags: linux, ssd, filesystems, arch-linux, ata

Once in every 2-3 weeks when i try to open an application on linux, my system freezes for half a minute then continues like nothing happened continuing without issues.

My laptop:

```
cpu:                                                            
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz, 2500 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz, 1000 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz, 2500 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz, 2500 MHz
keyboard:
  /dev/input/event4    AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
mouse:
  /dev/input/mice      AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint
chipcard:
                       Broadcom 5880
monitor:
                       FDM42 B125HAN LCD Monitor
graphics card:
                       Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
sound:
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
storage:
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
network:
  wlp1s0               Intel Wireless 8260
  enp0s31f6            Intel Ethernet Connection I219-LM
network interface:
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  enp0s31f6            Ethernet network interface
  wlp1s0               Ethernet network interface
disk:
  /dev/sdb             SanDisk Ultra Fit
  /dev/sda             LITEON L8H-256V2
partition:
  /dev/sdb1            Partition
  /dev/sda1            Partition
  /dev/sda2            Partition
  /dev/sda3            Partition
usb controller:
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
                       Intel Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #11
hub:
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
memory:
                       Main Memory
bluetooth:
                       Intel Bluetooth wireless interface
unknown:
                       FPU
                       DMA controller
                       PIC
                       Keyboard controller
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP PMC
                       Realtek RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
                       Intel Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
                       Broadcom 5880
  /dev/input/event9    Realtek Integrated_Webcam_HD
```

My filesystem layout:

```
NAME                      FSTYPE      FSVER LABEL     UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
/dev/sda                                                                                                  
├─/dev/sda1               vfat        FAT32           A727-4587                             436.2M    15% /boot
├─/dev/sda2               ext2        1.0   cryptswap 9a12aaf5-70d7-4542-8f7e-06ec84bfb6e3                
│ └─/dev/mapper/swap      swap        1     swap      40a22eb2-2d33-47ea-83de-59b5f166a23b                [SWAP]
└─/dev/sda3               crypto_LUKS 2               7f8cace2-10ae-4cb0-a776-f4784d2c27d6                
  └─/dev/mapper/cryptroot btrfs                       17c65db2-3c0a-4a7f-b9e6-40927253858c  221.3G     3% /var/log
                                                                                                          /home
                                                                                                          /.snapshots
                                                                                                          /
```

mount:

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3938552k,nr_inodes=984638,mode=755,inode64)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755,inode64)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/mapper/cryptroot on / type btrfs (rw,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,discard=async,space_cache,subvolid=256,subvol=/@)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=608)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/cryptroot on /.snapshots type btrfs (rw,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,discard=async,space_cache,subvolid=259,subvol=/@snapshots)
/dev/mapper/cryptroot on /home type btrfs (rw,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,discard=async,space_cache,subvolid=257,subvol=/@home)
/dev/mapper/cryptroot on /var/log type btrfs (rw,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,discard=async,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/@var_log)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=3950776k,nr_inodes=409600,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=790152k,nr_inodes=197538,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

All related dmesg messages:

```
[  185.280105] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x7e3fff8 SErr 0x40000 action 0x6 frozen
[  185.280130] ata3: SError: { CommWake }
[  185.280143] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280150] ata3.00: cmd 60/b0:18:e8:74:58/02:00:03:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq dma 352256 in
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280178] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280187] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280192] ata3.00: cmd 60/a0:20:28:78:58/04:00:03:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq dma 606208 in
                        res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280215] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280224] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280231] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:28:80:7e:58/01:00:03:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq dma 131072 in
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280267] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280276] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280283] ata3.00: cmd 60/78:30:28:80:58/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq dma 61440 in
                        res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280315] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280324] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280330] ata3.00: cmd 60/78:38:38:81:58/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq dma 61440 in
                        res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280359] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280367] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280374] ata3.00: cmd 60/80:40:18:82:58/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq dma 65536 in
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280406] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280417] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280424] ata3.00: cmd 60/98:48:28:83:58/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 77824 in
                        res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280458] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280468] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280475] ata3.00: cmd 60/40:50:c8:84:58/01:00:03:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq dma 163840 in
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280511] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280522] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280530] ata3.00: cmd 60/c8:58:90:86:58/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 11 ncq dma 102400 in
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280568] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280579] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280588] ata3.00: cmd 60/e8:60:48:88:58/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 12 ncq dma 118784 in
                        res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280626] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280637] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280645] ata3.00: cmd 60/10:68:f0:89:58/01:00:03:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq dma 139264 in
                        res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280682] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280694] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280702] ata3.00: cmd 61/08:70:68:50:6c/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 4096 out
                        res 40/00:01:01:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280734] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280745] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280754] ata3.00: cmd 61/08:78:70:51:6c/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 4096 out
                        res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280787] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280797] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280804] ata3.00: cmd 61/a0:80:e0:d9:d9/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 81920 out
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280834] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280843] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280851] ata3.00: cmd 61/00:88:50:ef:d9/02:00:01:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 262144 out
                        res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280884] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280894] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280902] ata3.00: cmd 60/88:a8:08:86:58/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 21 ncq dma 69632 in
                        res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280938] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.280949] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.280956] ata3.00: cmd 60/f0:b0:58:87:58/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 22 ncq dma 122880 in
                        res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.280992] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.281005] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.281014] ata3.00: cmd 60/c0:b8:30:89:58/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq dma 98304 in
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.281070] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.281082] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.281089] ata3.00: cmd 60/d0:c0:00:8b:58/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq dma 106496 in
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.281125] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.281136] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.281143] ata3.00: cmd 60/a8:c8:d0:8b:58/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 25 ncq dma 86016 in
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.281168] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.281174] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  185.281179] ata3.00: cmd 60/20:d0:40:64:44/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 26 ncq dma 16384 in
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  185.281199] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  185.281211] ata3: hard resetting link
[  185.593723] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[  185.597521] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  185.597555] ahci 0000:00:17.0: port does not support device sleep
[  185.597644] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  185.597655] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  185.597663] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  185.597670] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  185.597675] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  185.597687] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  185.597698] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  185.597703] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  185.597708] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  185.597713] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  185.597750] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=42s
[  185.597762] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  185.597771] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  185.597780] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 03 58 74 e8 00 02 b0 00
[  185.597785] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 56128744 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 7 prio class 0
[  185.597910] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=42s
[  185.597924] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  185.597933] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  185.597941] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 03 58 78 28 00 04 a0 00
[  185.597946] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 56129576 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 10 prio class 0
[  185.598019] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=42s
[  185.598032] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  185.598044] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  185.598058] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 03 58 7e 80 00 01 00 00
[  185.598065] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 56131200 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[  185.598140] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=42s
[  185.598160] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  185.598174] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  185.598189] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 03 58 80 28 00 00 78 00
[  185.598197] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 56131624 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[  185.598697] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=42s
[  185.598709] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  185.598720] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  185.598734] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 03 58 81 38 00 00 78 00
[  185.598739] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 56131896 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[  185.599072] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=42s
[  185.599086] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  185.599099] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  185.599112] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 03 58 82 18 00 00 80 00
[  185.599119] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 56132120 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[  185.599211] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=42s
[  185.599223] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  185.599240] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  185.599253] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 03 58 83 28 00 00 98 00
[  185.599260] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 56132392 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[  185.599323] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=42s
[  185.599336] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  185.599347] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  185.599357] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 03 58 84 c8 00 01 40 00
[  185.599364] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 56132808 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
[  185.599425] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=42s
[  185.599437] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  185.599448] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  185.599459] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 03 58 86 90 00 00 c8 00
[  185.599466] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 56133264 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[  185.599516] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=42s
[  185.599528] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  185.599540] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  185.599550] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 03 58 88 48 00 00 e8 00
[  185.599557] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 56133704 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[  185.600932] ata3: EH complete
```

this happened 3-4 times in the last 2-3 months (on different distros as well), i didnt notice any dataloss after these events, checked filesystem - no corruption, i checked the drive with smartctl, i even checked the whole drive with badblocks command with all data cleared from the drive,tested ram with memtest86, and no issues whatsoever.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on with my laptop?

Comment: `I/O error` could be from a failing drive or a failing SATA cable. Run SMART tests; change the SATA cable.

Comment: there is no sata cable, it is a sata ssd drive in an m.2 slot in a notebook